Set theory terminology: how can I formally describe the type of N:N binary relations that can be represented by two tables?
Usually, many-to-many relationships between two sets/tables X and Y are represented in data systems using a third "join" table, which is a list of pairs of elements from X and Y indicating related elements. This is a standard practice for database design.
However, under certain conditions, you can represent the N:N relationship X<>Y with the two tables only. Informally, of all related objects/rows belong to "clusters", where all members of the cluster in X relate to all members of the same cluster in Y, for all clusters and all related rows, then you can have a "cluster ID" in each table and represent the relation with the two tables only.
Formally, how do I describe this? What is the formal property of the relation that allows the relation to be represented in this way?

I guess the property is that for all $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $X$ and $y_1$ and $y_2$ in $Y$, if $x_1 \mathrel{R} y_1$ and $x_2 \mathrel{R} y_2$, and $x_1 \mathrel{R} y_2$, then $x_2 \mathrel{R} y_1$. I don't know of a name for it, though.

Apparently this is called a difunctional or rectangular relation. « In 1997 researchers found "utility of binary decomposition based on difunctional dependencies in database management." »

Writing $C$ for the set of clusters, you have two functions $X \overset{f}{\to} C \overset{g}{\leftarrow} Y$ such that your relation is the pullback (or fibred product) $X \times_C Y$.
Apparently this is called a difunctional or rectangular relation.

In 1997 researchers found "utility of binary decomposition based on difunctional dependencies in database management."

